# Codename one - why is my TableLayout modified when going back from another Form?

Tags: java, codenameone

Here is my problem: I have a Form which contains several tabs. In the first one, I have a Table which contains information. My problem is that, when I open a new Form (let's say, a Dialog) and then closes it, my Table layout is unexpectedly modified. The same behavior is observed if I open a new Form, then use the back button.

I have set up a minimal example here below, with only one tab, which illustrates the problem:

```
public class spmonMobileApp {
    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;   
    private Table table;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);        
    }

    public void start() {           
        Form tabsForm = new Form("", new LayeredLayout());
        Tabs tabs = new Tabs(Component.BOTTOM);
        Container mainContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {""}, new Object[][] {{"MCR"}, {"SSR"}, {"HQ"}}, false);

        table = new Table(tableModel) {
            @Override
            protected Component createCell(Object value, int row, int column, boolean editable) { // (1)
                Component p = new Label((String)value);

                p.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xFFFF00);
                p.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
                p.getAllStyles().setAlignment(CENTER);

                p.addPointerPressedListener(new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        //createDataForm((String)value).show();
                        System.out.println(((TableLayout)table.getLayout()).isGrowHorizontally());
                        Dialog.show("Example", "Just a test", "OK", "Cancel");
                        System.out.println(((TableLayout)table.getLayout()).isGrowHorizontally());
                    }
                }); 

                return p;
            }
        };

        ((TableLayout)table.getLayout()).setGrowHorizontally(true);
        mainContainer.add(table);

        tabs.addTab("Welcome", mainContainer);
        tabsForm.add(tabs);

        tabsForm.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

In particular, it can be seen that isGrowHorizontally() is true before opening the dialog, and false afterwards (hence the labels being shrinked).

The visual consequence can be seen in the following picture (left is before opening a dialog (desired behaviour), right is after closing it):

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOMlQ.png)

So, does anyone know why it does that? And if so, does anyone know how to solve the issue (or what I am doing terribly wrong :-))?

If not, does anyone know how to make the cells span the entire width of the screen and keep it that way even after the Dialog is closed?

Thanks in advance !

Deneb

Comment: A very well written first question. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks! I just hope someone has a solution, because I am running out of ideas personally :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you relied on `Table` keeping the same layout instance but that isn't the case. The instance of the layout is replaced whenever the table is refreshed.

The "right" way to do this is to define a constraint for the table cell such as:

```
table = new Table(tableModel) {
   protected TableLayout.Constraint createCellConstraint(Object value, int row, int column) {
       TableLayout.Constraint c = super.createCellConstraint(value, row, column);
       c.setWidthPercentage(-2);
       return c;
   }


  ... rest of your code
};
```

-2 is a special case that gives the column the full width. In this case I applied it to all the cells but you should probably give it to only one column so you should condition that statement.